# Confused by a (standard?) gradient estimate.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

This sort of inequality appears frequently in a paper I'm reading, but never with any justification.

Take $u(x) \in H^{1}(B(x_{0}, r))$ and a cutoff $\phi(x) \in C_{0}^{\infty}(B(x_{0}, r))$ where $\phi \equiv 1$ on $B(x_{0}, r/2)$ and $|\nabla \phi| \leq 2C /r$. Then we have:

$$\int_{B(x_{0}, r)} |\nabla u| |u|\cdot \phi |\nabla \phi|\, dx \leq 2C \int_{B(x_{0}, r)}\phi^{2} |\nabla u|^{2}\, dx$$

Thank you so much for any enlightenment.

Comment: Is this the exact inequality? Not $(\nabla u) u\cdot \phi \nabla \phi$ on the left side?

Comment: Absolute values appear in the inequality (see (19) on p 10 of Kurata's paper at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.143.810 ).

Comment: I'm going to the library now to get Aronson and Serrin's paper "Local behavior of solutions of quasilinear parabolic equations", which I believe is more likely to contain details of this sort of argument. Will report back later.

Comment: Interlibrary loan. :(

Comment: :( I looked at the paper you gave earlier today though...couldn't follow some of the argument, I will discuss it with my officemate tomorrow see if he got any clue.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a link to the final version of Kurata's paper: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35887192/J.%20London%20Math.%20Soc.-2000-Kurata-885-903.pdf

Comment: The final version is extensively rewritten, with better typesetting. But nothing is essentially different in the proof of the "Caccioppoli-type inequality". (It starts on p894.)

Comment: In the paper $u$ is a solution of a parabolic PDE (which is not mentioned in the question), and integration happens with respect to time as well.